# Utilizing Meteor's OAuth-only package "mdg:facebook"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, meteor

I am utilizing a Facebook OAuth flow in a project (without accounts-facebook), and came across this MDG package: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/facebook. Is this even needed? Why so? In essence, can't the oAuth flow be done without using Meteor?

Anyways, this seems to be something I need, but I can't find any information on it except the single link to the official Meteor Accounts page. If anyone could provide some basic guidance, it would be a huge help.